# how to sum of column in codeigniter database class?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli, codeigniter-2

I want to sum a column data if date is in between some predefined date.

i am doing this with core php is like

```
SUM(IF(`trl`.`entrydate` between '2015-01-01' and '2015-01-31', `trl`.`itemvalue`, 0))
```

So how can i do it with codeigniter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with active records:

```
    $this->db->select_sum('data');
    $this->db->where("entrydate between 'x' and 'y' ");
    $query = $this->db->get('your table');
```

with query :

```
$this->db->query("select SUM(data) from `your table` where entrydate between 'x' and 'y' ");
```